# I can't pass v3 from chrome extension manifest v2

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I take the html code of the page with the plugin and send it with the form.
I need to change the 'content_security_policy' part to be able to switch to v3. But it doesn't work somehow, I get jquery error every time.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
     file: "source.js"
   }, function() {
```

In this part

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(null, {
     file: "source.js"
   }, function() {
```

I changed to.

Comment: Review the [official documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript): you shouldn't be passing `null` as the first argument.

Comment: Ok I got it done but I can't add jquery. I looked at the documentation but it didn't work.

Comment: You can inject jQuery as any other script: `chrome.scripting.executeScript({files:["jquery.js", "source.js"], ... `.